# Using arithmetic equations in Python

Tags: python

is there a way to round the value down to the lowest integer for this?

```
x = 5.5
z = 1

x -= z
```

x is just 4.5 in this case

but I want something like this

```
x = int(x - z)
```

which produces x as 4 but i would like to use the '-='

is there a way?

Comment: No. There's not a way to make `-=` convert type, thankfully.

Comment: `x int()-= z` (that's a joke)

Comment: `x = int(x - z)` wouldn't be any less efficient, because `x -= z` has to create a new object anyway: `float` values are immutable.

Comment: *" but i would like to use the '-='"* Why?

Answer (score 2):

No unfortunately there isn't a way to do exactly what you described. Your best option would be to do `x=int(x-z)` or if you want to round up in the case that `x=4.5` and preserve the `float` type, `x=round(x-z)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 5.5
a = 1
x -= a
x = int(x)
```

Try this. It will work

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a dedicated solution:

```
import math
math.floor(x-z)
```

It will always give you lower integer value (in fact it will be a float type but with an integer value).

Note that for `round(0.7) == 1.0`!!